# Mail app up/down arrows

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to get access to the up/down arrows used in the Mail app and implement them the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no supported way to do it.  I'd suggest you file a bug on Radar asking Apple to include more built-in artwork.  In the mean time, you'll just have to draw your own.

Answer (score 3):

Can you clarify your question?

The graphics for up/down are not easily accessible, though you can probably find a way to get them. For instance, see http://0xced.blogspot.com/2009/04/extract-uikit-artwork.html.

But if you're looking for the behavior, it's really quite simple. The arrows are on a momentary `UISegmentedControl`. Attach to `valueChanged:` to tell when the user taps on one of them, and use `selectedSegmentIndex` to tell which one they tapped.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays they are part of the sample code of IOS 4.1. Check the NavBar sample.

Answer (score 0):

As Steven Fisher said, you can’t access the Apple graphic easily. But they are relatively easy to remake.

Given the images I had some trouble making this look right in iOS 7 where a `UISegmentedControl` will not work. This code did the trick however (added to `viewDidLoad` in the ViewController).

```
UIButton *upButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[upButton setImage:[upImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]
          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
upButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 6);
[upButton sizeToFit];

UIButton *downButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[downButton setImage:[downImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
downButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 6, 0, 0);
[downButton sizeToFit];


UIBarButtonItem *upButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:upButton];
UIBarButtonItem *downButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:downButton];

[upButton addTarget:self action:@selector(YOUR_UP_SELECTOR:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[downButton addTarget:self action:@selector(YOUR_DOWN_SELECTOR:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[downButtonItem, upButtonItem];
```